# Excel-VBA Coy both lowercase and uppercase letter

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim i, LastRow


LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:I500").ClearContents
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Singapore" Then

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If

Next i
```

Can anyone tell me how to write code so it would copy both this name Singapore and signapore in lower or uppercase? it will only copy Singapore not small letter singapore

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match `Singapore` and `singapore` (and any other variation of upper/lowercase letters) you need to use case-insensitive comparison.

The easiest way is to convert both side to either uppercase or lowercase and then do the comparison.

```
If UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value) = "SINGAPORE" Then
```